# rpmbuild Installed (but unpackaged) files source

Tags: linux, packaging, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an RPM from binaries on a REDHAT 6 system. I have all the files included in the `%files` section (`find /path/to/fake/install -type f >> specfile`)

When I run `rpmbuild -bb specfile --target x86_64`  I get

```
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /path/to/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Package-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:

RPM build errors:
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
```

Note that no files are listed in the error message. I'm not sure what's wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 26):

You can ignore these kind of errors by using

```
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
```

[See also](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s07.html)

Comment: To people coming here from google: The above answer is dangerous and should be used very carefully.  Before resorting to this very carefully look at your %build and %install sections and make sure you've accounted to every file they generate in the %files section

Comment: @SonofaSailor if your properly testing your RPM it shouldn't be an issue, but I agree this should only be used for initial development of the rpm as there is also the %ghost directive which would serve better to ignore (not include) installed files that you don't want in the package.

Answer (score 14):

I would guess your /path/to/fake/install is not correct.

The path in the `%files` section must be the path where the files will eventually be installed, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/myprog`. During the rpm build, in the `%build` section you need to make sure you put the files to the very same place you specify in the `%files` section, or you use the `buildroot` option of `rpmbuild` and use `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` variable in your spec file with a sub-path matching the `%files` list, in this example `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/myprog`. See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-anywhere.html for details.

Comment: Please note that I'm generating the RPM from existing binaries (no %build). My %files look something like:

/usr/share/foo

/opt/foo/bar

And my dir structure is:

/path/to/rpmbuild/usr/share/foo

/path/to/rpmbuild/opt/foo/bar

Comment: Doy you set the buildroot option to /pat/to/rpmbuild when running rpmbuild?

Comment: @Bernhard http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-anywhere.html link is dead (and it's not on https://web.archive.org/).

Answer (score 0):

One example where this may happen: Supposing in the `%post` section there is a `%install_info` and in the `%postun` section there is an associated `%install_info_delete`. This requires in the `%install` section an explicit removal of the intermediate directory of the info-files with a command like `rm -f %{buildroot}/%{_infodir}/dir`.